# how to call click() function for a textbox in gwt

Tags: java, gwt, button, textbox, onclick

When I click a button, I want it to give click a textbox beside it. However, just giving focus to the textbox wont work. I actually need to click it, the user can do it manually but how do I do it programmatically?

```
Button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {   
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            //Click the texbox
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why do you want two click events at the same time?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin the user will click a button, and that much give focus to a textbox which the user will type in. However, if i just do a textBox.setFocus(true), the softkeyboard doesnt show up if I am using phonegap to make this into a mobile app. So I decided, why dont i force manually click the textbox since that shows the softkeyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a native event on an element:

```
NativeEvent event = Document.get().createClickEvent();
DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(event, myTextBox);
```

Comment: Hi, this doesnt seem to work for a suggestionBox which extends a textbox, any ideas why?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not seem to work"?

Comment: Even if I do this, I assumed this will give focus to textbox (since its a click) and open up the virtual/soft keyboard, however none of those things seem to happen

Comment: I have the exact same need/problem with my suggestbox/virtual keyboard. Since you accepted the answer I would like to know the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is funny, is almost the same solution that I proposed in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935481/how-to-show-hide-virtual-keyboard-in-gwt-phonegap-as-textbox-receives-focus).

Solving your problem with [GQuery](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) it should be easy, something like:

```
//add TextBox and Button to the DOM

GQuery.$(button).click(new Function() { public void f() {
   GQuery.$(textBox).click();
}});

//if you want to test if the click event has been fired
GQuery.$(textBox).click(new Function() { public void f() {
  Window.alert("Text Box clicked");
}});
```

I have not tested personally the code, so if you have any error or doubt, just let me know :)

Comment: Thanks for giving me an insight towards GQuery, however I am using Java and dont want to use GQuery. Any ideas how to fire click event on a textbox using java?

Comment: Yes! Follow the path that @Andrei just wrote. Be sure that the element which is going to receive the event has sunk it before :)

Comment: im sorry what do you mean by element has sunk it before? :P

Comment: Oh! Trying to sumarize, sinking eventas is the way how Gwt knows which browser events should 'receive/listen' each widget through the onBrowserEvent method.

Comment: GQuery *is* Java, its a Java port of JQuery, written for GWT.